# Warning vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded

Tags: linux, kernel, virtualbox

Well I run this command

> aptitude purge ~o

To delete all the Obsoletes files that aptitude show me big mistake I guess after that I update the system everything works fine but when I restart the system and I want to load the virtual machine I got this error

```
WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
         available for the current kernel (3.14-kali1-amd64) or it failed to
         load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by

           sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup

         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
```

The program still running but I can't load the virtual machine so I run that command to and the out put was.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.
Recompiling VirtualBox kernel modules ...failed!
  (Look at /var/log/vbox-install.log to find out what went wrong)
```

I am going to post just one part of the file because vbox-install.log have to many lines.

```
./install.sh: 343: ./install.sh: /etc/init.d/vboxautostart-service: not found
./install.sh: 343: ./install.sh: /etc/init.d/vboxballoonctrl-service: not found
./install.sh: 343: ./install.sh: /etc/init.d/vboxweb-service: not found
VirtualBox 4.3.10 r93012 installer, built 2014-03-26T19:18:38Z.

Testing system setup...
System setup appears correct.

Installing VirtualBox to /opt/VirtualBox

Output from the module build process (the Linux kernel build system) follows:

make KBUILD_VERBOSE=1 SUBDIRS=/tmp/vbox.0 SRCROOT=/tmp/vbox.0 CONFIG_MODULE_SIG= -C /lib/modules/3.12-kali1-amd64/build modules
make -C /usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-kali1-amd64 \
    KBUILD_SRC=/usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-kali1-common \
    KBUILD_EXTMOD="/tmp/vbox.0" -f /usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-kali1-common/Makefile \
    modules
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (        \
    echo >&2;                           \
    echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";       \
    echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
    echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";  \
    echo >&2 ;                          \
    /bin/false)
mkdir -p /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_versions ; rm -f /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_versions/*
make -f /usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-kali1-common/scripts/Makefile.build obj=/tmp/vbox.0
```

The last part.

```
make -C /usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-kali1-amd64 \
    KBUILD_SRC=/usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-kali1-common \
    KBUILD_EXTMOD="/tmp/vbox.0" -f /usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-kali1-common/Makefile \
    modules
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (        \
    echo >&2;                           \
    echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";       \
    echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
    echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";  \
    echo >&2 ;                          \
    /bin/false)
mkdir -p /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_versions ; rm -f /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_versions/*
make -f /usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-kali1-common/scripts/Makefile.build obj=/tmp/vbox.0
   gcc-4.7 -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/linux/.VBoxPci-linux.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-kali1-common/arch/x86/include -Iarch/x86/include/generated  -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-kali1-common/include -Iinclude -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-kali1-common/arch/x86/include/uapi -Iarch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-kali1-common/include/uapi -Iinclude/generated/uapi -include /usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-kali1-common/include/linux/kconfig.h   -I/tmp/vbox.0 -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -O2 -m64 -mno-mmx -mno-sse -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -funit-at-a-time -maccumulate-outgoing-args -fstack-protector -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_FXSAVEQ=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fomit-frame-pointer -g -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/SUPDrvMangling.h   -I/lib/modules/3.12-kali1-amd64/build/include   -I/tmp/vbox.0/   -I/tmp/vbox.0/include   -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux   -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxpci/   -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxpci/include   -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxpci/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBOX_WITH_HARDENING -DRT_ARCH_AMD64 -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS  -DMODULE  -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(VBoxPci_linux)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(vboxpci)" -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/linux/.tmp_VBoxPci-linux.o /tmp/vbox.0/linux/VBoxPci-linux.c
   gcc-4.7 -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/.VBoxPci.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-kali1-common/arch/x86/include -Iarch/x86/include/generated  -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-kali1-common/include -Iinclude -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-kali1-common/arch/x86/include/uapi -Iarch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-kali1-common/include/uapi -Iinclude/generated/uapi -include /usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-kali1-common/include/linux/kconfig.h   -I/tmp/vbox.0 -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -O2 -m64 -mno-mmx -mno-sse -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -funit-at-a-time -maccumulate-outgoing-args -fstack-protector -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_FXSAVEQ=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fomit-frame-pointer -g -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/SUPDrvMangling.h   -I/lib/modules/3.12-kali1-amd64/build/include   -I/tmp/vbox.0/   -I/tmp/vbox.0/include   -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux   -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxpci/   -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxpci/include   -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxpci/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBOX_WITH_HARDENING -DRT_ARCH_AMD64 -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS  -DMODULE  -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(VBoxPci)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(vboxpci)" -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_VBoxPci.o /tmp/vbox.0/VBoxPci.c
   gcc-4.7 -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/.SUPR0IdcClient.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-kali1-common/arch/x86/include -Iarch/x86/include/generated  -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-kali1-common/include -Iinclude -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-kali1-common/arch/x86/include/uapi -Iarch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-kali1-common/include/uapi -Iinclude/generated/uapi -include /usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-kali1-common/include/linux/kconfig.h   -I/tmp/vbox.0 -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -O2 -m64 -mno-mmx -mno-sse -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -funit-at-a-time -maccumulate-outgoing-args -fstack-protector -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_FXSAVEQ=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fomit-frame-pointer -g -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/SUPDrvMangling.h   -I/lib/modules/3.12-kali1-amd64/build/include   -I/tmp/vbox.0/   -I/tmp/vbox.0/include   -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux   -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxpci/   -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxpci/include   -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxpci/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBOX_WITH_HARDENING -DRT_ARCH_AMD64 -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS  -DMODULE  -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(SUPR0IdcClient)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(vboxpci)" -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_SUPR0IdcClient.o /tmp/vbox.0/SUPR0IdcClient.c
   gcc-4.7 -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/.SUPR0IdcClientComponent.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-kali1-common/arch/x86/include -Iarch/x86/include/generated  -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-kali1-common/include -Iinclude -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-kali1-common/arch/x86/include/uapi -Iarch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-kali1-common/include/uapi -Iinclude/generated/uapi -include /usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-kali1-common/include/linux/kconfig.h   -I/tmp/vbox.0 -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -O2 -m64 -mno-mmx -mno-sse -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -funit-at-a-time -maccumulate-outgoing-args -fstack-protector -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_FXSAVEQ=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fomit-frame-pointer -g -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/SUPDrvMangling.h   -I/lib/modules/3.12-kali1-amd64/build/include   -I/tmp/vbox.0/   -I/tmp/vbox.0/include   -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux   -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxpci/   -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxpci/include   -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxpci/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBOX_WITH_HARDENING -DRT_ARCH_AMD64 -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS  -DMODULE  -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(SUPR0IdcClientComponent)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(vboxpci)" -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_SUPR0IdcClientComponent.o /tmp/vbox.0/SUPR0IdcClientComponent.c
   gcc-4.7 -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/linux/.SUPR0IdcClient-linux.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-kali1-common/arch/x86/include -Iarch/x86/include/generated  -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-kali1-common/include -Iinclude -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-kali1-common/arch/x86/include/uapi -Iarch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-kali1-common/include/uapi -Iinclude/generated/uapi -include /usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-kali1-common/include/linux/kconfig.h   -I/tmp/vbox.0 -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -O2 -m64 -mno-mmx -mno-sse -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -funit-at-a-time -maccumulate-outgoing-args -fstack-protector -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_FXSAVEQ=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fomit-frame-pointer -g -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/SUPDrvMangling.h   -I/lib/modules/3.12-kali1-amd64/build/include   -I/tmp/vbox.0/   -I/tmp/vbox.0/include   -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux   -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxpci/   -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxpci/include   -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxpci/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBOX_WITH_HARDENING -DRT_ARCH_AMD64 -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS  -DMODULE  -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(SUPR0IdcClient_linux)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(vboxpci)" -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/linux/.tmp_SUPR0IdcClient-linux.o /tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPR0IdcClient-linux.c
  ld -m elf_x86_64   -r -o /tmp/vbox.0/vboxpci.o /tmp/vbox.0/linux/VBoxPci-linux.o /tmp/vbox.0/VBoxPci.o /tmp/vbox.0/SUPR0IdcClient.o /tmp/vbox.0/SUPR0IdcClientComponent.o /tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPR0IdcClient-linux.o 
(cat /dev/null;   echo kernel//tmp/vbox.0/vboxpci.ko;) > /tmp/vbox.0/modules.order
make -f /usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-kali1-common/scripts/Makefile.modpost
  find /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_versions -name '*.mod' | xargs -r grep -h '\.ko$' | sort -u | sed 's/\.ko$/.o/' | scripts/mod/modpost -m  -i /usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-kali1-amd64/Module.symvers -I /tmp/vbox.0/Module.symvers  -o /tmp/vbox.0/Module.symvers -S -w -s -T -
   gcc-4.7 -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/.vboxpci.mod.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-kali1-common/arch/x86/include -Iarch/x86/include/generated  -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-kali1-common/include -Iinclude -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-kali1-common/arch/x86/include/uapi -Iarch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-kali1-common/include/uapi -Iinclude/generated/uapi -include /usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-kali1-common/include/linux/kconfig.h   -I/tmp/vbox.0 -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -O2 -m64 -mno-mmx -mno-sse -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -funit-at-a-time -maccumulate-outgoing-args -fstack-protector -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_FXSAVEQ=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fomit-frame-pointer -g -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/SUPDrvMangling.h   -I/lib/modules/3.12-kali1-amd64/build/include   -I/tmp/vbox.0/   -I/tmp/vbox.0/include   -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux   -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxpci/   -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxpci/include   -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxpci/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBOX_WITH_HARDENING -DRT_ARCH_AMD64 -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS  -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(vboxpci.mod)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(vboxpci)" -DMODULE  -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/vboxpci.mod.o /tmp/vbox.0/vboxpci.mod.c
  ld -r -m elf_x86_64 -T /usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-kali1-common/scripts/module-common.lds --build-id  -o /tmp/vbox.0/vboxpci.ko /tmp/vbox.0/vboxpci.o /tmp/vbox.0/vboxpci.mod.o
Starting VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.

End of the output from the Linux kernel build system.
Installation successful
Makefile:183: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.
Makefile:183: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.
Makefile:183: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.
```

thank you very much for any help or comments.

Comment: I had a similar problem. A couple of nights ago, `vagrant up` worked just fine. Today, I get the fun "check the logs" error.

Running

`sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup`

solved it for me. I did pull down some updated Ubuntu files in the meantime - perhaps that caused the problem and required the recompile?

Comment: Did not recompile anything instead of mess with that stuff that honestly didn't understand why is happen that. am just re install VirtualBox again. But am gonna try that to see what happen.

Comment: Check [my answer in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38437264/i-cant-execute-command-modprobe-vboxdrv/59536913#59536913), maybe could help :)

Answer (score 21):

for Ubuntu 15.10 and virtualbox 5.+ use:

> sudo /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup

thx:
http://www.webupd8.org/2015/10/workaround-for-sbinvboxconfig-not.html

Comment: It also works for Zorin 12.3 (xenial - Ubuntu 16.04). But, first I had to install this: https://askubuntu.com/a/779427/584541

Answer (score 14):

I met the problem:

## VBoxManage --version

WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
         available for the current kernel (4.6.3-300.fc24.x86_64) or it failed to
         load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by

```
       sudo /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup

     You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
```

5.0.24_RPMFusionr108355

After I do

> sudo modprobe vboxdrv

Then it works now.

Comment: worked for me with manjaro Linux. Did not have to reinstall or remove anything

Comment: If anyone having error with modprobe "Operation is not permitted" - try disabling secure boot from bios menu.

Answer (score 13):

On Arch Linux

```
sudo pacman -S virtualbox-host-modules-arch
```

and then

```
sudo modprobe vboxdrv
```

Comment: @selmansamet, isn't this a great platform for a mutual help. I was also having trouble with it and it took me couple of ours to solve it by poking. Next time I may find your answer that you figured before me.

Comment: None of other answers worked for me, except this. Thank you. `Kernel: 5.3.5-arch1-1-ARCH`

Answer (score 4):

For me, I did an update to the system and run again `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup` after that.

Answer (score 3):

Run:

`sudo /usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh setup`

It should fix the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Arch Linux:

```
sudo pacman -S virtualbox-host-modules-arch
```

And then you have to reboot. That fixed it for me.

Tring to restart could work on other distrobutions, too.

Answer (score 1):

Select the right version. For me was 3.13-kali1

I think that you are missing something.
Try to install

- linux-headers-3.14-kali1-common
- linux-headers-3.14-kali1-amd64
- linux-source-3.14
- libdw1
- libunwind7

it worked for me.

Best Regards.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I am just delete all the related files and them re-install, works like a charm thank God.

Answer (score 1):

On Debian, try:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

When all the missing dependencies are resolved, try launching VirtualBox again.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo modprobe vboxdrv` worked for me, right after I've disabled secure boot from bios menu.

Answer (score 1):

Just disable secure-boot from bios, it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

**For Arch Linux:**

**First step:**

```
pamac install virtualbox $(pacman -Qsq "^linux" | grep "^linux[0-9]*[-rt]*$" | awk '{print $1"-virtualbox-host-modules"}' ORS=' ')
```

**next step:**

```
sudo modprobe vboxdrv
```

Comment: This comment put me on the right track. It gave me the error 'linux414-virtualbox-host-moduls not found'. Turned out that I still had a lot of old kernels installed which apparently messed with virtualbox as well.

Answer (score 0):

This guide is what got it working for me: https://gorka.eguileor.com/vbox-vmware-in-secureboot-linux-2016-update/

I am however using Ubuntu 16.04 (I am not sure which distro the guide is using..) and I modified these steps as:

`for f in $(dirname $(modinfo -n vboxdrv))/*.ko; do echo "Signing $f"; sudo /usr/src/kernels/$(uname -r)/scripts/sign-file sha256 ./MOK.priv ./MOK.der $f; done`

becomes:

`for f in $(dirname $(modinfo -n vboxdrv))/*.ko; do echo "Signing $f"; sudo /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/scripts/sign-file sha256 ./MOK.priv ./MOK.der $f; done`

---

`mokutil --import MOK.der`

becomes:

`sudo mokutil --import MOK.der`

---

Otherwise it got it working for me.

Answer (score 0):

This command worked for me

sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup

Next I got following error

The VirtualBox VM was created with a user that doesn't match the
current user running Vagrant. VirtualBox requires that the same user
is used to manage the VM that was created. Please re-run Vagrant with
that user. This is not a Vagrant issue.
The UID used to create the VM was: 0
Your UID is: 1000

That got solved by running vagrant up command with root access.

this should fix the issue with VirtualBox Version: 5.1

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands to fix.

First one:

`uname -r`

this will give you, you kernel version exemple : linux kernel 4.16.03

take the 3 first number then run this second command replacing those 416 with your value:

this command is for manjaro linux but you can try to install the package with apt get:

`sudo pacman -S linux416-virtualbox-host-modules`

the last command to initialise the module:

`sudo modprobe vboxdrv`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to fix the .deb downloaded from Oracle, I did:

```
sudo aptitude install virtualbox
```

and it worked! Well, I had to remove the broken package first.
(Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)

Answer (score 0):

After install VirtualBox on ubantu 18.04.3

- download and install virtualbox-dkms related to your virtualbox version
- download virtualbox-dkms packages links urls reference

(https://pkgs.org/download/virtualbox-dkms)
OR
(http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/contrib/v/virtualbox/)

after download i.g virtualbox-dkms.deb package install using below command

```
$ sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-dkms.deb
```

---

Follow steps in this URL (http://www.bojankomazec.com/2019/04/how-to-install-virtualbox-on-ubuntu-1804.html)

Answer (score 0):

> sudo apt install -f

then you can run your virtualbox, this command fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

When installing VirtualBox to Fedora 36 using conventional methods (adding RPM repository and then installing with `dnf`), I ended up with kernel modules with `*.ko.xz` extension(`vboxdrv.ko.xz`, `vboxnetadp.ko.xz`, `vboxnetflt.ko.xz`). From what I understand `kmods` modules were not properly compiled. As a result, when trying to load modules (with `modprobe vboxdrv`) I got the following error even though I did sign them correctly.

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'vboxdrv': Invalid argument
```

It seems to be an issue specific to Fedora 36, as I had a similar issue with `v4l2loopback` module. The solution is not to use the default repository to install and instead download the release `.rpm` files from official sources and install manually. After manually downloading and installing the resulting `kmod` modules did not have that `.xz` extension and did load correctly after signing them.

Answer (score 0):

I simply load the kernel module at boot.
As sudo, add the line `vboxdrv` to the file `/etc/modules` and reboot. **This only works with secure boot disabled in the BIOS.**
You can check if secure boot is disabled by running `mokutil --sb-state`.

Answer (score 0):

on Ubuntu i executed in terminal: sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
This solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

After reading through most of the answers here is what helped me: I uninstalled a bunch of old kernels (I currently am on 5.18-MANJARO, but had Kernels all the way back to 49 still installed). It seems like it messed with virtualbox as well. I uninstalled the old kernels, then installed the most recent virtualbox-host-modules (54, 510, 515) and now virtual box can start virtual machines again.