# I can't execute command modprobe vboxdrv

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I recently upgraded my laravel vagrant box. Since then, Virtual box is giving me the same error

> The provider 'virtualbox' that was requested to back the machine
>   'default' is reporting that it isn't usable on this system. The reason
>   is shown below:
>
> VirtualBox is complaining that the installation is incomplete. Please
>   run `VBoxManage --version` to see the error message which should
>   contain instructions on how to fix this error.

So, making a little research I found that the kernel driver is not available. I tried to install it and give me the following error when it tries to execute `modprobe vboxdrv`.

> modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'vboxdrv': Required key not available

I have 4 days with this error and I don't know what to do. Somebody can help me?

Comment: Is it secureboot enabled: http://askubuntu.com/questions/760671/could-not-load-vboxdrv-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04-and-i-want-to-keep-secur

Comment: @HRgiger believe me, I googled that but it didn't work

Comment: Ok I do but last shot :) http://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-dkms-modules

Comment: @HRgiger what are the implications to unable secure boot?

Comment: Try this [virtualbox forum post](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=77363&start=15#p361135)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got into same problem

Solved it by disabling secure boot option.

Go to BIOS configuration and disable secure boot.

Comment: Sure I disabled secure boot option but the Insecure booting warning drives me crazy everytime I boot my computer

Comment: Disabling security mechanisms is not really a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 63):

This is a solution which doesn't involve disabling the Secure Boot:

The problem is that the `vboxdrv` module is not signed and therefore not loaded with the kernel. This will happen if your computer has the SecureBoot mode activated, something very common in modern equipment.

That's why I get this error opening any machine in the Virtual Box

> Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

Do the following steps to sign a driver, and it is loaded as a kernel module:

**1.** Install the `mkutil` package to be able to do signed.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install mokutil
```

**2.** generate the signature file:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout MOK.priv -outform DER -out MOK.der -nodes -days 36500 -subj "/CN=VirtualBox/"
```

**3.** Then add it to the kernel:

```
sudo /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/scripts/sign-file sha256 ./MOK.priv ./MOK.der $(modinfo -n vboxdrv)
```

**4.** Register it for the Secure Boot.

**IMPORTANT!** That will ask you for a password, put the one you want, you will only have to use it once in the next reboot.

```
sudo mokutil --import MOK.der
```

**5.** Finally, restart the computer. A blue screen will appear with a keyboard wait, press the key that asks you to interrupt the boot.

[image]

When you are inside the blue screen, select

```
Enroll MOK > Continue > Yes > and it will ask you for the password
```

that you have previously entered, you will enter it and you will be informed that the operation has been completed successfully.

Now your operating system will start and you can now use VirtualBox without problem :)

I tested this in Ubuntu, Kubuntu and Debian. Hope this help someone.