# Error when trying to start minikube

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, minikube, ubuntu-18.04

I try to start minikube with `minikube start` but i get the following error:

> charlie@charlie:~$ minikube start Starting local Kubernetes v1.10.0
>   cluster... Starting VM... E0705 00:39:35.199099   20888 start.go:168]
>   Error starting host: Error creating host: Error executing step:
>   Running precreate checks. : We support Virtualbox starting with
>   version 5. Your VirtualBox install is "WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel
>   module is not loaded. Either there is no module\n         available
>   for the current kernel (4.15.0-23-generic) or it failed to\n
>   load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by\n\n
>   sudo /sbin/vboxconfig\n\n         You will not be able to start VMs
>   until this problem is fixed.\n5.2.12r122591". Please upgrade at
>   https://www.virtualbox.org.
>
> Retrying.

I tried starting the virtualbox but i get the following error:

> charlie@charlie:~$ virtualbox 
>   WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is
>   not loaded. Either there is no module
>            available for the current kernel (4.15.0-23-generic) or it failed to
>            load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by
>
> ```
>        sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
>
>      You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
> ```

I tried running `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig` but i get the following error:

> charlie@charlie:~$ sudo /sbin/vboxconfig vboxdrv.sh: Stopping
>   VirtualBox services. vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
>   vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services. vboxdrv.sh: Building
>   VirtualBox kernel modules. vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv
>   failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.
>
> There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up
>   process, run   /sbin/vboxconfig as root.

I tried as root but still the error above even though i am root.
I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with minikube v0.28.0

Comment: There is some clarification needed. The problem is probably with VirtualBox installation.
1) How did you install the VirtualBox?  Did you use official documentation for that? https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads#Debian-basedLlinuxdistributions
if not try to reinstall with this instructions . 
2) Is Secure Boot turned on?

Comment: the instalation of virtualbox was done according to the instructions on the site and the secure boot is disabled

Comment: Maybe [this answer I just posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39030662/cant-install-virtualbox-in-arch/59536730#59536730) can help you

Comment: Check [my answer in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38437264/i-cant-execute-command-modprobe-vboxdrv/59536913#59536913), maybe could help :)

Answer (score 2):

I tried to recreate the problem, and it is for sure Virtualbox on Ubuntu 18.04 specific. As I can't remove secure boot on my laptop to fully check it, I tried some solutions from the forums, but secureboot stands on my way. I would suggest trying install linux-headers, dist-upgrade and check if you have the required packages:

```
sudo apt-get -y install gcc make linux-headers-$(uname -r) dkms

sudo apt-get install dkms
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

So if this does not work, I suggest using different vm-driver. You can use 
minikube start --vm-driver=none or try different hypervisor. I can also say that it does work if Ubuntu 18.04 is a VM while using --vm-driver=none.

Answer (score 2):

**Just having the exact issue.**

```
leo@tmv:~/dev/kubernetes$ minikube start --kubernetes-version v1.9.4
Starting local Kubernetes v1.9.4 cluster...
Starting VM...
E0430 16:10:25.962867    1225 start.go:180] Error starting host: Error creating host: Error executing step: Running precreate checks.
: We support Virtualbox starting with version 5. Your VirtualBox install is "WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module\n         available for the current kernel (4.15.0-47-generic) or it failed to\n         load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by\n\n           sudo /sbin/vboxconfig\n\n         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.\n5.2.22r126460". Please upgrade at https://www.virtualbox.org.

 Retrying.
E0430 16:10:25.964185    1225 start.go:186] Error starting host:  Error creating host: Error executing step: Running precreate checks.
: We support Virtualbox starting with version 5. Your VirtualBox install is "WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module\n         available for the current kernel (4.15.0-47-generic) or it failed to\n         load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by\n\n           sudo /sbin/vboxconfig\n\n         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.\n5.2.22r126460". Please upgrade at https://www.virtualbox.org
E0430 16:10:27.905310    1225 util.go:151] Error uploading error message: Error sending error report to https://clouderrorreporting.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/k8s-minikube/events:report?key=AIzaSyACUwzG0dEPcl-eOgpDKnyKoUFgHdfoFuA, got response code 400
```

**It's VM issue.**
**Solution**:

- fully remove (include all the vm images files) and reinstall virtualbox 6
- if using ubuntu 18 - https://tecadmin.net/install-virtualbox-on-ubuntu-18-04/

After installation, try `virtualbox` cmd, if no issues, then you should be good to `minikube start`